# Database design in DynamoDB: Bookmark storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm interested in best practices on how set up tables and indices for given query requirements. I have a basic understanding of related concepts such partition and sort keys or LSI and GSI secondary indices, but have problems putting it all together and designing one or more table with indices that supports a palpable example.

The example i'm looking at is a "Bookmark storage", where multiple users can store bookmarks to URLs and annotate those with a number of tags. A `User` has multiple `Urls` (= bookmark). Each `Url` has a date and can have one or more `Tags`.

A bookmark might have the following basic structure:

```
{
  "user": "watQuadrat",
  "url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
  "date": 1494161436362,
  "tags": [ "forum", "programming" ]
}
```

My biggest question at this point is how to setup the table structure so that I can accommodate the various different ways the data could be queried, e.g.:

- List all `Tags` for a `User`, sorted by how often the user used a tag
- List all `Tags` for a `User`, sorted alphabetically
- List all `Tags` for an `Url`, sorted by how often this tag was given for the url
- List all `Tags` matching a given search string, sorted by how often the tag was used (e.g. search for "shop", return all tags that match such as "shopping" order by how often they were used)
- List all `Urls` for a `User`, sorted by date
- List all `Urls` for a `User` and a `Tag`, sorted by date
- List all `Urls` for a `Tag`, sorted by how often the tag was given to each url
- List all `Users` for an `Url`, sorted by date

How would this be designed so i can perform all of these queries in a performant way? Would you design this any different when additionally trying to reduce cost?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the scenario you have described, I would design the table as mentioned below. Here I have assumed that one user can create only one bookmark from a given url. And also I have used a new derived attribute called **TagCount** which denotes the count of tags for that bookmark.

**Table Structure**

Primary partition key : UserID

Primary sort key : Url

**Local Secondary Indexes**

*Index 1*

Partition key : UserID

Sort key : Date

*Index 2*

Partition key : UserID

Sort key : TagCount

**Global Secondary Indexes**

*Index 1*

Partition key : Url

Sort key : Date

*Index 2*

Partition key : Url

Sort key : TagCount

With this design you can do your queries in the following manner.

- List all Tags for a User, sorted by count

  *Query using LSI UserID-TagCount*
- List all Tags for an Url, sorted by count

  *Query using GSI Url-TagCount*
- List all Tags matching a given string, sorted by count

  *I assume the string you meant here belongs to url. If so you will have to perform a scan*
- List all Urls for a User, sorted by date

  *Query using LSI UserId-Date*
- List all Urls for a User and a Tag, sorted by date

  *Query LSI UserId-Date table with a filter expression for searching tag*
- List all Urls for a Tag, sorted by count

  *You will have to do a scan here*
- List all Users for an Url, sorted by date

  *Query GSI Url-Date*

If you are concerned about the cost. You can loose some GSIs based on the query patterns you would expect.

***Update 1***

Considering the updated requirement, since there are many queries based on the tag, I think there should be a second table with the following structure

Primary partition key : TagName
Primary sort key : UserID

**Global Secondary Indexe**

Partition key : UserID

Sort key : Usage - *Derived attribute similar to tag count, total usage of the tag*

Comment: I was thinking about using the user identifier as the partition key and the url as sort key aswell. By reading your answer, i realized that i had not described my query requirements precisely enough so i updated my question accordingly. I hope the query requirements are understandable now.

Thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: Hey this is interesting. I updated the answer based on the updated requirement you had mentioned.